# Can you write to an Entity Framework database using plain SQL

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Can someone help me answer these questions on EntityFramework?

1. Does it do anything special to the database? (like extra tables)
2. Can I add data directly with SQL without breaking EF?
3. Can I add tables and fields without breaking EF?

Comment: Entity Framework is not a database - it's a database **access** technology....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access database with plain SQL when using EF.

1. No. EF just uses database. There is one exception in code first approach where EF can create one additional table for its own purpose called `EdmMetadata`.
2. Yes you can add data directly with SQL. If both your entity model and database are defined correctly it will not break EF.
3. Yes you can add new tables directly but EF will not know about them. You should not change existing tables because it can break EF.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
var context = new YourObjectContext();
var s = context.ExecuteStoreCommand("some query");
```

if your query create a table, this only create a table on db and not effected on EF

Comment: I know about ExecuteStoreCommand, but your answer does not really address my question.

Comment: Illustrate your question with extra description to answer and question near to them.